# What does Peter mean by "peace" in Acts 10:36?

Tags: acts, soteriology

> As for the word that he sent to Israel, preaching good news of **peace** through Jesus Christ (he is Lord of all),
> (Acts 10:36, ESV)

> τὸν ⸆ λόγον ⸀[ὃν] ἀπέστειλεν τοῖς υἱοῖς Ἰσραὴλ εὐαγγελιζόμενος **εἰρήνην** διὰ Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ, οὗτός ἐστιν πάντων κύριος,
> (Acts 10:36, NA28)

Speaking to Cornelius Peter likely spoke in Greek.  However, Peter also likely had the Hebrew word שָׁלוֹם (shalom) in mind.

**Figure 1.** Words εἰρήνη translates in the Tanakh (generated with Logos Bible Software)

[image]

In case someone thinks this support a prosperity gospel, remember Jesus' worlds to the Apostles:

> I have said these things to you, that in me you may have peace. In the world you will have tribulation. But take heart; I have overcome the world.
> (John 16:33, ESV)

Does Peter's use of peace have his conclusion (forgiveness of sins) in mind considering the verbal root  שָׁלוֹם (shalom) comes from is used for [restitution in the Torah](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/79419/is-the-term-%D7%A9%D6%B8%D7%81%D7%9C%D6%B9%D7%95%D7%9D-peace-in-isaiah-535-usually-misunderstood).

> To him all the prophets bear witness that everyone who believes in him receives forgiveness of sins through his name.”
> (Acts 10:43, ESV)

Comment: See my answer to your previous question at https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/79419/is-the-term-%d7%a9%d6%b8%d7%81%d7%9c%d6%b9%d7%95%d7%9d-peace-in-isaiah-535-usually-misunderstood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BDAG essentially comments on this verse in **Acts 10:36** by suggesting its meaning is:

> Since according to the prophets, peace will be an essential
> characteristic of the messianic kingdom (...), Christian thought also
> frequently regards εἰρήνη as nearly synonymous with messianic
> salvation (Isa 52:7), Acts 10:36; Rom 10:15 v.1; Eph 2:17; τοῦ
> εὐαγγελίου τῆς εἰρήνης Eph 6:15. ...

See also John 16:33, Rom 5:1, John 14:27, 2 Thess 3:16b, etc.

Ellicott:

> **Preaching peace**.—Better, as reproducing with the Greek the thought and language of Isaiah 52:7, preaching glad tidings of peace.

Matthew Henry:

> The purport of this word was, that God by it published the good
> tidings of peace by Jesus Christ. They knew the several matters of
> fact relating to the gospel. They knew the baptism of repentance which
> John preached. Let them know that this Jesus Christ, by whom peace is
> made between God and man, is Lord of all; not only as over all, God
> blessed for evermore, but as Mediator.

Barnes:

> **Peace** - This word ... is used here in a wider sense, to denote "peace or reconciliation with God." He announced the way by which man
> might be reconciled to God, and might find peace.

Gill:

> **preaching peace by Jesus Christ**: that word preached, or the apostles in the ministry of it preached; or rather God, who sent the
> word by them, preached through them the doctrine of peace and
> reconciliation, by the blood of Christ; and this being so principal a
> doctrine of the Gospel, the whole is called from it, the Gospel of
> peace, and the word of reconciliation: by "peace" here is meant ...
> peace with God, which was broken by the sin of man, which filled his
> mind with enmity to God; and now he is incapable of restoring it, and
> reconciling himself to God;

See also [Is the term שָׁלֹום (peace) in Isaiah 53:5 usually misunderstood?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/79419/is-the-term-%d7%a9%d6%b8%d7%81%d7%9c%d6%b9%d7%95%d7%9d-peace-in-isaiah-535-usually-misunderstood)